# "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file" while compiling for x64 architecture on Windows 7

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

I have encountered a problem while trying to compile simple example with boost using Visual Studio 2012 Pro. I have downloaded and compiled boost succesfully (ver 1.54.0). I have compiled 32 bit version (Win32 configuration) of example in both release and debug version. Then I made an attempt to build for 64 bit (as I have 64 bit Windows 7). I followed the instruction here: [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9yb4317s.aspx). Alas, the compilation attempt failed with error:

```
1>server.cpp(38): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/aligned_storage.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I checked the following points and now I'm out of ideas what could be wrong:

1. The file is in correct place (exact location: C:\dev\include\boost\boost\aligned_storage.hpp). If it hadn't been there then the Win32 version wouldn't have compiled.
2. I have set the environment variable INCLUDE as "C:\dev/include;C:\dev/include/boost" .
3. "VC++ Directories->Include Directories" looks like this:

> $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);$(INCLUDE);

1. "C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories" like this:

> C:\dev\include\boost;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

The code I'm trying to compile is (this is only part of it of course):

```
//
// server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2013 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//


#ifndef WINVER                  // Minimum platform is Windows 7
#define WINVER 0x0601
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT            // Minimum platform is Windows 7
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS          // Minimum platform is Windows 7
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0601
#endif

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/aligned_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
```

Content of my x64\Debug\BoostExample.log:

```
Build started 2013-07-15 19:45:53.
 1>Project "C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\BoostExample\BoostExample.vcxproj" on node 2 (Build target(s)).
 1>ClCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc110.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:prompt server.cpp
     server.cpp
 1>server.cpp(38): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/aligned_storage.hpp': No such file or directory
 1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\BoostExample\BoostExample.vcxproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.28
```

For comparison here is Release\BoostExample.log (for succesfull 32bit compilation):

```
Build started 2013-07-15 20:06:17.
 1>Project "C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\BoostExample\BoostExample.vcxproj" on node 2 (Build target(s)).
 1>ClCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc110.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt server.cpp
     server.cpp
   Link:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\Release\BoostExample.exe" /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\Release\BoostExample.pdb" /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\Release\BoostExample.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH Release\server.obj
     Generating code
     Finished generating code
     BoostExample.vcxproj -> C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\Release\BoostExample.exe
 1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\LF\Develop\BoostExample\BoostExample\BoostExample.vcxproj" (Build target(s)).

Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.50
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :D.

Thanks in advance
Lehu

Comment: Perhaps, you accidentally configured the include directories for an incorrect configuration? Ensure that "Configuration:" and "Platform:" comboboxes show the appropriate values.

Comment: Open x64\Debug\projectname.log file, this is full build log. It contains C++ compiler command line, like: `CL.exe /c /I...` /I switch should contain `C:\dev\include` directory: `/IC:\dev\include` What do you see in this log?

Comment: Also, C:\dev\include\boost in Additional Include Directories is wrong, should be C:\dev\include

Comment: I added content of my BoostExample.log. The strange thing is that it does not contain /I switch...
Regarding Additional Include Directories: the header file is in _C:\dev\include\boost\boost\_ not _C:\dev\include\boost\_ so I figured out that one "boost" should be removed, while the other should remain. I will try your suggestion.